# How set dynamically xml to iframe in that way that browser parsed it?

Tags: javascript, xml, iframe

If open xml document in browser it is parsed by it and I can open or close nodes and many other futures are present, is there a way to set xml to iframe by javascript and it was parsed in the same way?
Xml I get now by ajax response.

Comment: you can use css to do what you expect : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp

Comment: Till now I was doing it, but it doesn't give me functionality that give the browser (open and close nodes).